# Is there a way to make sure any alterations to a table's schema also get applied to another table?

Tags: mysql, triggers, schema

Suppose I create a duplicate of a table, for auditing purposes:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_audit LIKE my_table;
```

I'll then use triggers to make sure any updates to `my_table` make it into `my_table_audit`, in some generic way (no references to specific column names).

Is it also possible to create "meta" triggers, then? So that if anyone were to add or remove a column from `my_table`, the same would happen on `my_table_audit`.

Comment: I think you're talking about replication. As such, this might be better directed towards the dba forum.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe use a programming language script as an API for creation and syncing.

Comment: sounds like a sql change subversion system? Why not version your `.sql` files/changes in subversion software?